# How to customize validation functions for some field?

Tags: 8, entities

I have the standard node add or edit form.
The edited node has several fields.
How can I customize validation functions for a field ?
For example, I need to switch off or change validation function for some field.
How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to add a validation for a entity field and that validation can work in any form you can use [entity validation constraints](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-validation-api/providing-a-custom-validation-constraint), and add programatic validations.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_base_field_info_alter().
 */
function foo_entity_base_field_info_alter(array &$fields, EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
  // Add Bar constraint to the user name.
  /** @var \Drupal\Core\TypedData\DataDefinitionInterface[] $fields **/
  if ($entity_type->id() == 'user' && !empty($fields['name'])) {
    $fields['name']->addConstraint('Bar');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @ivan-jaros says, you can use [entity validation constraints](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-validation-api/providing-a-custom-validation-constraint) to add new validations to a field. In the hook he mentions you can also get the current validations and remove what you don't need.

You can also use [hook form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/hook_form_alter) of node edit form and use the #element_validate (more info [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21FormElement.php/class/FormElement/8.2.x)) property to add / remove custom validations.